# Grafana removes some points in line graph depending on time range

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I have a Grafana line graph that pulls counts from a Prometheus DB. When the chart is shown in last 1 hour, it shows a point for every 15s which is the frequency that Prometheus scrapes. However, when I change to last 24 hours, it shows a point for every 1 minute. Instead of grouping those 15s points in 1 minute, it just shows the point for every minute.

For example, I have example points below:

11:54:00 = 350

11:54:15 = 450

11:54:30 = 300

11:54:45 = 200

11:55:00 = 250

On the last 1 hour view, Grafana shows all five points, but on the last 24 hours view, it only shows the 00 second points, ignoring the data at 15, 30, and 45. What I would expect would be either the 24 hour view to show every point, or to add the points together per minute (ex. 11:55 would be 1300 for the last minute).

I have tried playing around with the resolution, but it is set to 1/1 for the 24 hr graph. I am guessing I have something set to auto, but I cannot determine which setting is causing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically, what I had to was use $__interval in my query instead of specifying a time vector for the delta function I was using.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you need to adjust the "Min Step" (which is left blank by default for auto-adjusting):
[image: Grafana Legend settings]
The "Min Step" tool tip explains the following: "Leave blank for auto handling based on time range and panel width. **Note that the actual dates used in the query will be adjusted to a multiple of the interval step**."

Comment: I have tried this, and for the 24hr view, it appears that the minimum step cannot get to 15s, so I am still only seeing a point every minute

Comment: I guess what I am looking for is either every point (which doesn't seem to work) or to put the data into buckets for whatever minimum resolution I can use, instead of it only creating points at some interval and ignoring the data in between.

Comment: Seems you're right and Grafana ignores the "Min Step" altogether when scaling to 24 hours (for instance).
If you want to see every point, try sum for [1m] of your counts. It's ugly but will at least give you the "buckets" you look for

Comment: That is still not quite what I need. When I try that I am still missing points. This is what I see https://i.imgur.com/3XFkocW.gif

Comment: If I understand what I see in the gif, this is the sum (of the last X minutes you put there) as you requested. Not sure what points you're missing now, if you've aggregated them.